# Cross Referencing Data in CSV Files

Tags: go

I have two CSV files, the first is about 18 MB, and the second is about 3.2 GB.

What I am looking to do is check if column 2 in the first CSV, matches any of the rows in column 4 of the second CSV file.

Essentially like inner joining 2 tables in MySQL.

Whats the best way to achieve this in-memory using Go?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What problems did you encounter?

Comment: "second is about 3.2 GB" it's a decent bit of data to dig through, but to me it sounds like you only need to keep the 4th column in memory.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.